# Unable to use SQL Anywhere Sybase packages for Java + SQL Anywhere 17 does not install Sybase Central in any systems

Tags: java, spring, maven, sybase, sqlanywhere

There are two parts to this question.

I have been trying to install and test SQL Anywhere Sybase connection using an existing project in Eclipse. I did the following:

- Installed SQL Anywhere 17
- Navigated to the SQL Anywhere 17 Java folder and used the following command to install `sajdbc4.jar`:

  ```bash
  mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path/to/sajdbc4.jar> -DgroupId=com.sqlanywhere -DartifactId=sajdbc4 -Dversion=17.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
  ```
- Added the following POM dependency:

  ```xml
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sqlanywhere</groupId>
    <artifactId>sajdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>17.0.0</version>       
  </dependency>
  ```
- Tried importing:

  `com.sqlanywhere.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.SQLAnywhereDriver`

  But It gave me a "Cannot be resolved" error
- Tried `mvn clean install`, it didn't work.

This is my code:

```java
public Map<String,String> getServiceStatuses() throws Exception {
    var obj = new HashMap<String,String>();
    obj.put("status","success");
   
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.sqlanywhere.jdbc4.sqlanywhere");
     
      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(10);
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlanywhere:uid=abc;pwd=def;eng=xyz");
      if(conn.isClosed()) {
          System.out.println("This is closed");
      } else {
          System.out.println("This is open");
      }
      
   } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   
   return obj;
}
```

Now using this code I haven't been able to test a SQL Anywhere Sybase driver yet, which brings me to my second question.

When I installed SQL Anywhere 17, Sybase Central, which is required to setup a Sybase SQL Anywhere server in my local didn't get installed. I tried installing SQL Anywhere 17 in a different machine and it still wouldn't install Sybase Central. I downloaded the trial version by logging in to their website. I installed the developer  version. I uninstalled and reinstalled and "Custom" this time which still didn't show the Sybase Central option. I couldn't find anything helpful online pertaining to this

Sorry about the horrible formatting, if someone can help me with this it would be great. I am not sure if I installed sajdbc4 within the local mvn repo the right way and I have no way of testing this since I couldn't install Sybase Central.

Answer (score 0):

In getServiceStatuses(){}
use

> Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.SQLAnywhereDriver");
> //for registering

For the second question : Sybase Central is no longer included in the SQL Anywhere 17 package.
So, try using third party database management tools or command line tools.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I'll try it out, could you also tell me what jar file I should install and what the maven dependency in my pom should be? Cause when I try to do an import to check if it's being picked up by pom as expected, it doesn't do it. Even com.sybase.